# Cancelled flight, single booking. Should each passenger make separate claims?

Tags: cancellations, delays, compensation

My flight has been cancelled. I flew another day, which resulted in over 24 hours delay. The airline is based in the EU and so is the destination airport.

I have a single booking for two passengers. Should I make a single claim for both passengers, or should each passenger make separate claims for compensation?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already begun the process, [Europa.EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) has the form which can be used to lodge a complaint with the airline and/or national authority. It lets you include all passengers affected.

> **Claim your rights**
>
> **Step 1 : Complain to the airline**
>   You should first send your complaint to the airline using the [**EU-wide air passenger rights complaint form**](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/air/doc/complain_form/eu_complaint_form_en.pdf).
>
> **Step 2 : Complain to national authorities**
>   If you don't receive a reply from the airline within 2 months or if you are not satisfied with the reply, and if you consider that your EU air passenger rights were not respected, you can lodge a complaint with the relevant [**national authority**](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/2004_261_national_enforcement_bodies.pdf) in the country where the incident took place, within a reasonable time-frame.
>
> The national authority should provide you with a non-binding legal opinion on how to proceed with your claim.